How do I create a dynamic table with corresponding line graphs that I can filter based on samplepoint?
I need a dynamic table and two line graphs (one for yeast and one for mold for each samplepoint) that I can filter by samplepoint.
The goal is to be able to select the samplepoint from a dropdown and have it populate the dynamic charts for yeast and mold.
The horizontal axis would be the create dates, and the vertical axis would be the yeast (or mold) results for each date.
My data looks something like the table below. I am trying to minimize the size of the workbook by using the filtering method to filter by samplepoint.

Is this even possible in Excel?
What should the formula/code look like to achieve this?




Create Date
Samplepoint
Samplepoint Description
Yeast
Mold




6/18/24
000C
Negative Control
0
0


8/30/24
000C
Negative Control
0
2


3/19/24
Air 01
Line 1 Filler Room
0
0


4/9/24
Air 01
Line 1 Filler Room
0
0


3/16/24
Air 03
Line 3 Filler Room
0
0


3/28/24
Air 03
Line 3 Filler Room
1
1



I have tried the filtering formula (=Filter()), however the formulas have errors when populating the data that contains the individual dates, and it also tries to sum the results instead of populating the exact data for each date listed individually. The dropdown that I create also does not populate the sample points correctly.

I would use pivotcharts to accomplish this. Make a pivot table and pivot chart for it, copy that table so the datasource isn't duplicated unnecessarily, then do it for your second chart. Rightclicking the table, pivot table, or pivot chart gives you the option to refresh down the road. Add a slicer to re-filter the data.
